# My SQL query is failing to get low cost rooms at multiple rooms bookings

Tags: mysql, sql

Bellow is my "rooms" mysql table. (This is example table i have created to show here.)

[image]

I want to show low cost rooms in case multiple room bookings. Ex: User have select two room, 1 adult in first room and 2 adults in second room. Now my result should come as below

[image]

My Query is :  **SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE hotel_code="100"  GROUP BY adult+child Order by cost ASC**

It is not working. I am not able to get the expected result with this query. Please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `adult+child` with `adult, child`?

Comment: my company is blocking image services ( i guess you added db structure by image ) - but try to change `GROUP BY adult+child` to `GROUP BY adult,child` . (guessing your column isnt named "adult+child", then set it into ` s )

Comment: I haven't tried with adult, child

Comment: Ok. I will try as you suggested

Comment: No. Still expected result is not coming. row 3 and 1 results are coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  r.*
FROM Rooms r
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    adult, child, MIN(Cost) MinCost
  FROM Rooms
  WHERE hotel_code = 100
  GROUP BY  adult, child
) m ON r.adult = m.adult AND r.child = m.child
  AND r.cost = m.mincost
ORDER BY r.id
LIMIT 2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b341f/4)

This will give you:

```
| ID | HOTEL_CODE |    ROOM_TYPE | ADULT | CHILD | COST |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |        100 | Single Delux |     1 |     0 |   20 |
|  3 |        100 | Twin Stadard |     2 |     0 |   25 |
```

Comment: Good but 3 rows are coming. Cant we get without duplicates?

Comment: Good, but this (potentially) falls down if you have two single deluxes at the same (lowest) price.

Comment: @Strawberry Note that subquery will get the min cost grouped by `adult, child` so If this min cost was duplicate, then it is from different type e.g the min cost of adult type is 20 and min cost of child type is 20.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Mahmoud's thinking with a (less scalable) extension...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM rooms x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT hotel_code
                   , adult
                   , child
                   , MIN(cost) min_cost 
                FROM rooms 
               GROUP 
                  BY hotel_code
                   , adult
                   , child
            ) y 
           ON y.hotel_code = x.hotel_code 
          AND y.adult = x.adult 
          AND y.child = x.child 
          AND y.min_cost = x.cost
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM rooms x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT hotel_code
                   , adult
                   , child
                   , MIN(cost) min_cost 
                FROM rooms 
               GROUP 
                  BY hotel_code
                   , adult
                   , child
            ) y 
           ON y.hotel_code = x.hotel_code 
          AND y.adult = x.adult 
          AND y.child = x.child 
          AND y.min_cost = x.cost
     ) b
    ON b.hotel_code = a.hotel_code
   AND b.adult = a.adult
   AND b.child = a.child
   AND b.cost = a.cost
   AND b.id < a.id
 WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Bigggg..!. Thanks. It is satisfying the requirement.